# Run ghost in existing application on same port

Tags: node.js, ghost

All the solutions for running Ghost within an existing Node application seem to start Ghost on a separate port (2368) and somehow forward requests within `/blog` from their main application (eg running on port 3000) to this other port.

Is there any way to just have Ghost as part of the same application, so everything is on port 3000, without needing port 2368??

I'm asking, in case running on multiple ports is not an option provided by my node hosting service.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible.

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var ghost = require('ghost');

var app = express();
//set up application routes here
ghost().then(function (ghostServer) {
    app.use(ghostServer.config.paths.subdir, ghostServer.rootApp);
    ghostServer.start(app);
});
```

This is not officially supported as I understand. But we have this running on on [wordwith.com](http://www.wordwith.com) with the blog running on [wordwith.com/kb](http://www.wordwith.com/kb) both on the same port